# Limiting the number of results matching a certain value of field in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, grouping

I want to limit the number of results that match certain value of a certian field in SOLR. For example, field `group_id` has three values `a`, `b`, `c`. Now if i make a query `a` OR `b` OR `c` in `group_id` field, how can I limit the number of results that match that contain the value `b`.

I have studied the `Result Grouping` in solr in detail but could not find the support for such an operation. There is a thread available for `Lucene` but I think it is not yet available for `SOLR`. Here is the link for that:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6066

Comment: The patch you've linked says that it limits the result to any five of a retailer - is that what you're looking for, or just limiting the number for `b`?

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. I just want to limit the number of results that match `b`